# Jquery change data-src of an parent image

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have following html structor the content is added dynamically

```
<div class="media text-muted pt-3">
    <img data-src="holder.js/32x32?theme=thumb&bg=d32f2f&fg=d32f2f&size=1" alt="todo" class="mr-2 rounded">
    <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-bottom border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
            <strong class="text-gray-dark">{{ $ticketValue->title }}</strong>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
            <span class="d-block">
                <strong>Erstellt von {{ $ticketValue->description }}</strong>
            </span>
            <button type="button" class="closing-ticket" data-ticket-id="{{ $ticketValue->id }}">
                <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the user click on the button I would like to change the data-src of the current parent image tag.
So far I have done this:

```
this.closingTicket.click((e) => {
    let _this = $(e.currentTarget);
    axios.post('ticket/close/' + this.elements.closingTicket.attr('data-ticket-id'))
        .then((response) => {
            _this.hide(); // hides buttons
            // trying to find the image and change its data-src
            _this.parent().parent().parent().find('img').data('src', 'holder.js/32x32?theme=thumb&bg=64dd17&fg=64dd17&size=1');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // error
        })
});
```

Comment: Use `e.target`, not `e.currentTarget`.

Comment: @connexo does not help

Comment: I wouldn't even use jQuery here. Use `let _this = e.target;` and `_this.closest('.media').querySelector('img').dataset.src="holder.js/32x32?theme=thumb&bg=64dd17&fg=64dd17&size=1";`